# dropdown seletion form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms

I am trying to add a dropdown form with 1-100 numbers in wordpress.
in PHP i did it like this:

```
<select name="dolar[]">
<?php for ($i=0; $i<=75; $i++)
{
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i; ?><name="dolar"></option>
    <?php
} ?>
```

but I am confused about converting it to wordpress. I tried this:

```
 for ($i=0; $i<=75; $i++)
{

     $form.='<option value="'; $i; $form.='">';$i; $form.='<name="dolar"></option>';
}
```

$form.='';

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert your php to WordPress. It would work just fine, since WordPress is written in php.

One addition you could make would be to use a WordPress-specific function like [selected()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/).

```
<select name="options['opt']">
<?php for ($i=0; $i<=100; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php selected( $options['opt'], $i ); ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Of course there is more than one way to accomplish the same thing.

```
<?php 
    $opts = '<option value="">Select One</option>';
    for ($i=0; $i<=100; $i++) {
        $opts .= '<option value="'. $i .'" '. selected( $options['opt'], $i, false ) .'> '. $i .'</option>';
   } 
?>
<select name="options['opt']">
    <?php echo $opts; ?>
</select>
```